# Sequelize JS custom query with sub selects

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm new to ORM and I don't know to do this using an ORM. 
Considering that i have 5 tables:

tag, auction, user, user_tag and auction_tag

and I'm using SequelizeJS, how can I get a query like this?

```
select  A.id, A.title, A.content, A.createdAt, U.id, U.picture, U.name
from    Auction A, User U, User U2
where   A.userId = U.id and U2.id = x
and     exists (select  AT.id
            from    Auction_Tag AT
            where   AT.auction = A.id
            and     AT.tag in ( select  T.id
                                from    Tag T, User_Tag UT
                                where   U2.id = UT.user
                                and     UT.tag = T.id
                              )
           );
```

Any ideas? Thank you guys

Comment: I found the answer.
:
`sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT})
  .then(function(users) {
    // We don't need spread here, since only the results will be returned for select queries
  })`

Comment: Depending of the relations you have with the tables you can achieve that in more cleaner way (at least for a ORM), than using queries like that.

Answer (score 1):

Using an orm is suppose to abstract you from the query language itself.
If you are willing to do a nested request, you should use the "where" property of the options object you have to pass to the findAll method.
I'm unable to deduce your structure from the information you gave, so I'm putting an example with the best of my guesses (being Auction your auction model and userid the id relating it to user):

```
Auction.findAll({where: { userid: 8 }}).done(callback);
```

If, however, you are going for a related entity parameter, let's say User.name, go for it:

```
Auction.findAll({where: { 'User.name': 'John' }}).done(callback);
```

If you see yourself using SQL queries, maybe you should consider not using an ORM.